# DIfferent shaped HTML Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I have created a HTML Canvas and everywhere I have checked it has some width and height but I want my canvas to be of some shape for e.g. a Star or any other png image that can be converted into a canvas. I have tried few things like

```
<canvas class="question" id="canvas"></canvas>
<img src="img/11.png" id="scream">

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("scream");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
</script>
```

but all it does is it makes a canvas of sqaure shape with an image in it. I want the canvas to be shaped like the image.

Comment: Canvases, like most other HTML elements, are always rectangular.  You cannot have a star-shaped canvas element.  The only real *exception* to this that I can think of are SVG <path> elements, but even these need to be contained within an <svg> tag, which itself will always be rectangular.  What are you trying to do with a star-shaped <canvas>?

Comment: I am creating activities for students in which they can draw or fill colors in this canvas and not outside its border

Comment: Then you can clip() your canvas context, your canvas can stay rectangular

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. I hope this will help you

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

This code assigned image size to canvas.
As all images are coming in 2D so the canvas size must be either square or rectangle.

Comment: I am using png images without any background and I dont think it will work

Answer (score 0):

### Basic shape

The canvas can be any shape if you use the alpha (transparency) channel to make unwanted pixels transparent.

Example

```
    // draw image on canvas    
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", {alpha: true}); // alpha option is the default
                                                        // I added it to show my intent
    canvas.width = scream.width;
    canvas.height = scream.height;
    ctx.drawImage(scream, 0, 0);
```

Once the image is drawn on the canvas you can keep pixels by drawing over them using the [`globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation).

For example the following will make the canvas circular

```
    // draw a circle removing pixels outside the circle
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
    ctx.beginPath();
    const radius = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height) * 0.5;
    ctx.arc(canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.5, radius, 0. Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";  // restore default comp op
```

You can draw any shape, or use an image (eg SVG) to define the shape.

### Interactive shape

If you need the canvas to interact with pointer / mouse events that need to be aware of the shape use [CSS clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to define the shape.

Example using [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

```
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = scream.width;
    canvas.height = scream.height;
    ctx.drawImage(scream, 0, 0);
    const radius = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height) * 0.5;
    canvas.style.clipPath = "circle(" + radius + "px)";
```